# Update serialized fields without validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Foo
  store :custom_fields, accessors: [:bar1, :bar2, :bar3]

  validates :bar1, presence: true
  validates :bar3, presence: true
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar1 = 'hello'
foo.bar2 = 'hello again'

foo.save(validate: false) # => foo is now saved in the database

foo.update(bar2: 'an update to bar2') # => ERROR! since bar3 fails validation
```

Is there anyway to update without validating?  I found the update_columns method but it doesn't seem to work with serialized data like Active Record Store.

The alternative is to call foo.save(validate: false) every time, but I really want to update my data instead of inserting a new record every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply update the attribute and then call save:

```
foo.bar2 = 'an update to bar2'
foo.save(validate: false)
```

Comment: Holy crap... it's been a long day of work :)  Thank you.  I was creating a new object in the "create" action but I didn't realize you could just search for the object in the database and then call save(validate: false) to update it without inserting a new row.